# $|\phi(G):\phi(H)|$ divides $|G:H|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism defined on a finite group $G$, and let $H\subseteq G$. Show that $|\phi(G):\phi(H)|$ divides $|G:H|$.

Not quite sure where to start on this one. We have a theorem saying that $\phi(H)$ is a subgroup of $\phi(G)$, but what is $|\phi(H)|$? If $H$ contains the kernel $N$ of $\phi$, then I think everything behaves nicely and $|\phi(G):\phi(H)|=|G:H|$. But if $N\not\subseteq H$, I don't know what I can conclude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\phi(H) = \phi(NH)$ and $|\phi(G):\phi(NH)| = |G: NH|$.

Note that finiteness of $G$ is not necessary, we only need $|G: H|$ to be finite.

Comment: Are you saying that for every $\phi:G\longrightarrow G'$ group homomorphism, and for every $H$ subgroup of $G$, $(\ker \phi )H$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @julien This is well-known. It's enough that $NH = HN$ as sets, but since $N$ is normal, $Nh = hN$ elementwise for $h \in H$.

Comment: Right, thanks. I should review my basic algebra... I'll leave my comment for my punishment.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is finiteness, then we have that

$$|G:H|=|G|/|H|\text{,}$$

$$|\phi(G):\phi(H)|=|\phi(G)|/|\phi(H)|$$

and

$$|H:H\cap\ker\phi|=|H|/|H\cap\ker\phi|\text{.}$$

Here, remember that by the first isomorphism theorem and finiteness

$$|\phi(G)|=|G:\ker\phi|=|G|/|\ker \phi|$$

and

$$|\phi(H)|=|H:H\cap\ker\phi|=|H|/|H\cap \ker \phi|\text{.}$$

Now, do you see that everything is reduced to divide and rearrange terms in order to obtain the wanted divisibility?

Answer (score 2):

In one answer it is claimed that $G$ must be finite, in one answer it is claimed that we only need that $|G:H|$ is finite. In fact, no finiteness assumptions are necessary (on the other hand, in the infinite case, the statement is rather boring due to cardinal arithmetic).

Here is an alternative [bijective proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_proof), which is perhaps more conceptual and works without any finiteness assumptions: The map $G/H \to \phi(G)/\phi(H), [g] \mapsto [\phi(g)]$ is a well-defined surjective homomorphism of [$G$-sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action). Thus it suffices to prove:

> Lemma. If $f : X \to Y$ is a surjective homomorphism of $G$-sets and $X$ is transitive, then $|Y|$ divides $|X|$. Namely, if $y_0 \in Y$, then $|X|=|Y| \cdot |f^{-1}(y_0)|$.

Proof: Since $f^{-1}(gy)=g f^{-1}(y)$, every fiber of $f$ has the same cardinality $N$. Then $X = \coprod\limits_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(y)$ (as a set) witnesses $|X| = |Y| \cdot N$. $\square$

By the way, applying the Lemma to $G/K \twoheadrightarrow G/H$ for subgroups $K \subseteq H \subseteq G$, we get Lagrange's Theorem $|G:K|=|G:H| \cdot |H:K|$. It is also useful in other contexts.

Comment: @MartinBradenburg In my answer I use finiteness due to the question. However, I admit that your answer is much better conceptually. (Personally, I prefer this conceptual answer than the calculations approach I have shown.)